# How to verify the machine configuration using PhantomJS

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I have PhantomJS being used by karma-phantom-launcher plugin on my local machine. I want to get the machine configuration whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit.

Similar to what we can do with node.js i.e. after running node we can simply type
**process.arch** to get the machine configuration on which node is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will meet your requirement

```
var system = require('system');
var os = system.os;
console.log(os.architecture);  // '32bit'
console.log(os.name);  // 'windows'
console.log(os.version);  // '7'
```

You will get the informations in the console....

Answer (score 0):

A little digging in the documentation would show that you can use the [**system** module](http://phantomjs.org/api/system/) to do this:

```
var system = require('system');
console.log(system.os.architecture);
```